# Recruiter doesn't respond to my e-mail for a week. What should I do?

Tags: recruitment, email, united-kingdom

Sorry, my English is poor, but I'm a bit frustrated, so I need a piece of advice.

I am from Russia, and last Tuesday I got an e-mail from a large company's recruiter, who lives in another country, - she wrote that I could be a match for one of their teams. We had an informal chat, and then she asked me to suggest a couple of days suitable for a phone screen. She said that I can take as much time as I need to be prepared properly, but she suggested about 2 weeks for preparations. Unfortunately, we have a lot of exams in December, so last Wednesday I sent an e-mail asking if there is a possibility to be interviewed in January. She hasn't responded yet, and I am very nervous about that.

Should I write to her again? What actually should I ask?

Comment: What about calling the Person

Comment: If the other country is the US, that is important information.  Because of a holiday, no-one would likely reply in the latter part of last week.

Comment: @thursdaygeek Well, it's Great Britain

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with non-responsive recruiters for internships?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/how-do-i-deal-with-non-responsive-recruiters-for-internships)

Answer (score 2):

It never hurts to send an email as long as you don't do so frequently.  I would send an email and if you don't get a response in about 2 days, call them on the phone.

If nothing else, you need closure to determine if this is still something you're even in contention for.

Answer (score 2):

Hiring companies don't call back when they say they will, for all sorts of reasons:

- They get busy with other priorities
- Someone they need to talk to goes on vacation or holiday
- They go on vacation or holiday
- They need someone soon, so since you can't interview quickly, they move on to someone else
- The need for the job changed and they're stepping back to re-evaluate
- The money dried up and they won't be hiring after all
- They found an ideal candidate already
- They're about to call, but haven't yet

There are lots more reasons they may not have called.  And you have no way to know which reason it is.  Most of them have nothing to do with you.

You can contact her once, asking her what the next steps might be and a general idea of the timing.  After that, it's up to her to respond or not.  If you contact her several times, you risk annoying her and having her decide not to move on with you.  It's best to wait on that contact until at least several days after you expected to hear from her.

Once you have made that one contact, even before then, move on mentally.  Apply for other jobs.  If they want to hire you, they won't forget that.  But it's better to think that you are not being considered and being pleasantly surprised when they call, than to anxiously wait and be disappointed when they decide against you.

Comment: Actually it's a bit strange - she found me although I haven't applied for any of their positions, and then there's no answer.
I don't need a job right now - but it can be the only chance to work at that company for my whole life.
And surely they don't need someone for this position soon because she asked if I graduate next summer here, in Russia, or not.

Answer (score 1):

> last Wednesday I sent an e-mail asking if there is a possibility to be
>   interviewed in January. She hasn't responded yet, and I am very
>   nervous about that.
>
> Should I write to her again? What actually should I ask?

Since you haven't even waited a full week, and January is a long way away, you don't need to be too frustrated.

Wait at least one complete week.

If you still haven't heard any response, call her and say something like "I haven't heard from you yet, and just wanted to make sure you had my correct email address. Then, repeat you question about the possibility of waiting until January (or not)."